# How to get event properties from date in fullcalendar 3.1.0

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have this code in the `default.aspx`:

```
select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfCustomerId]").val(i.item.val);
                date = moment(i.item.label, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
                //$('#updatedialog').dialog('open');
```

I would like to get title, description etc. of the event to which the date corresponds.

I Have in default.aspx an input box  with a button:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[id$=txtSearch]").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/GetEvent") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {                           
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('|')[0] ,
                                val: item.split('|')[1]                                
                            }                            
                        }))
                        
                       },
                    error: function (response) {
                     //   alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfCustomerId]").val(i.item.val);
                date = moment(i.item.label, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
                $('#updatedialog').dialog('open');
               
            },
```

So I select only one event, and I would like that when the update dialog opens this is filled with title, description, etc

Comment: Your question makes no sense. `select` is used when you've clicked/dragged on an empty part of the calendar (presumably with the intention of creating a new event). If you want to get details of a specific event when it's clicked, you need to handle the [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventClick) callback instead.

Comment: Aside from that, `the event to which the date corresponds` also makes no sense. A date can contain multiple events, and an event can span across multiple dates. So it's not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve.,